# How to give a realistic 3D perspective to a 2D oval shape with zig zag effect pattern

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, 3d, patterns

[image: The Fence]

Hello all,
I am a illustrator noob who's trying to punch above it's weight too soon.
I am trying to draw an oval park which has an oval fence around it. The fence should follow the motive you can see below. 

[image]


So I drew two oval shapes and applied a zig-zag effect on the one I wanted to turn into the fence. I get the pattern I am looking for (very simplified, it's material design!), but then I can't get the perspective right!

I envelop distort it, which gives me the right dimensions at the top and at the bottom of the fence, but the left and right edges should be more "squeezed" to look more tridimensional from the "bird-eye" view I went for.

Do you have suggestions for a more appropriate way of working with this?

Comment: You have recently got an answer which gives a mathematically exact parallel projection (=seen from far away through a high zoom lens).

Answer (score 1):

a. Draw a circle

b. *Object > Path > Add Anchor Points*. Repeat to get as many segments as you require.

c. Copy and paste the circle, intersect them as shown below. Draw adjoining lines between the anchors with the Line Segment Tool <kbd>/</kbd>

[image]

1. Fill the bottom circle, and group everything
2. Select the graphic with the Selection Tool <kbd>V</kbd> and squash the whole graphic by clicking and dragging to distort it into an oval shape. Use the Direct Selection Tool <kbd>A</kbd> to bend the segments downwards. Repeat around the entire fence
3. The finished graphic

[image]

Comment: Consider to add the following developments: 1)double the anchors in the top ellipse, it makes downward bending easy(=drag). 2)insert an intermediate ellipse to be a visible downwards bending limit. Use a copy of the top ellipse with added anchors. 3) Convert the anchors at the top ends of the pylons to sharp, if needed.

Comment: @user287001 - That sounds like a great suggestion. Since you've commented, it's probably enough that the OP can read it. I'm not editing my answer. It already took me long enough ;)